# Why has my JSP application slowed down considerably since upgrading to Tomcat 8?

Tags: jsp, tomcat

Having upgraded a legacy JSP application from Tomcat 7/Java 7 to Tomcat 8/Java 8 the page response time has deteriorated noticeably; some pages take 4 or 5 times as long to load.
I've found this in the [JavaServer Pages 2.3 section](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html#JavaServer_Pages_2.3) of the Tomcat 8 migration notes:

"Unified Expression Language 3.0 added support for referencing static fields and methods. Supporting this feature in JSPs required changing the javax.servlet.jsp.el.ScopedAttributeELResolver implementation so that it also checked identifiers to see if they were names of imported classes or fields. In some circumstances, this change triggers significant slow down. This affects identifiers that may refer to a page, request, session or application scoped variable or may be undefined. When undefined, it takes significantly longer to resolve the identifier since it is now also checked to see if it is an imported class or field."

This goes some way to explaining the slow-down because the application includes many (100's) of .jsp and .tag files that include references to unscoped variables.  Sure enough, running strace on the Tomcat process I can see the class loader attempting to resolve these references e.g.

```
    Line 7063: 27709 13:42:46.248512 stat("/opt/tomcat/webapps/App/WEB-INF/classes/java/lang/width.class", 0x7f69cc9eb4f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    Line 7075: 27709 13:42:46.250092 stat("/opt/tomcat/webapps/App/WEB-INF/classes/javax/servlet/width.class", 0x7f69cc9eb4f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    Line 7085: 27709 13:42:46.251337 stat("/opt/tomcat/webapps/App/WEB-INF/classes/javax/servlet/http/width.class", 0x7f69cc9eb4f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    Line 7095: 27709 13:42:46.252548 stat("/opt/tomcat/webapps/App/WEB-INF/classes/javax/servlet/jsp/width.class", 0x7f69cc9eb4f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I see this behaviour every time a page is accessed.  I have two questions:

1.) Is there are way to configure Tomcat 8 to behave like Tomcat 7 in the way it treats unscoped variables so I don't have to trawl through 100's of .jsp and .tag files inserting the appropriate scope?

2.) Why does this happen every time a page is accessed?  I understand why it happens the first time, but once the page is compiled surely the JSP engine (Jasper) has worked out the correct scope.

Comment: Do you have `Filters` active? E.g. Compression Filter or alike? Can you try disabling all filters and time again?

Comment: It turns out the slow-down was due entirely to the new support for static fields and methods as mentioned in Tomcat 8 migration notes, referenced above.  The legacy application includes a large number of undefined variables.  Given the timescales I was working to, defining the scope of all these variables was impractical so for now I have reverted to Tomcat 7.  To answer my own questions: 1) No. 2) Because these are undefined variables they can only be resolved at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this article helps you, if you updated to Spring Boot 2.3.x in the process.

https://vivekvara.medium.com/jsp-performance-degrades-from-spring-boot-2-3-x-for-undefined-attributes-8cb434f743c2

It happens with undefined symbols in JSP Expression Language because of some class lookup.

> To avoid this slow down, code such as:
>
> ${undefined}
>
> should be replaced with:
>
> ${requestScope.undefined}